# How to store users global information in social network

Tags: php, memcached

I have a set of 20K users and I have a Feed just like facebook - lot's of comments, shares, likes. When I display the information I need some global user data (avatar, name, id). What is best practise for such case?

Should I just use mysql and JOIN user data for each post/publication? Or is it better to store the whole set of 20K users in memcache and use it from there?

At the moment I am using the second option - all users are being get from memcache into a 20M variable and I have performance issues.

I guess the memcache option is better since this data is used a lot. But in that case is it better if I have it in one big array (20M) or using single variable for every user is the key?

Comment: Sending 20 MB of data between servers for every request is pretty insane (as is having to update that entire cache item any time anything happens in your site). Cache individual items. You can have different types of item caches for different purposes, too. For a feed, you might cache the entire post's HTML, avatar and all, for a short period of time. You might separately cache the user's info for their profile.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot. If you can post it as an answer I will mark it as a solutin. My problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending 20 MB of data between servers for every request is pretty insane (as is having to update that entire cache item any time anything happens in your site). Cache individual items. You can have different types of item caches for different purposes, too. For a feed, you might cache the entire post's HTML, avatar and all, for a short period of time. You might separately cache the user's info for their profile.